# Getkeycodeforchar printing wrong JAVA

Tags: java

getExtendedKeyCodeForChar printing wrong:

Using this test class:

```
package test;

import iRobot.iRobot_Functions;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String admUsr = "HOMP\\adm03!@";
        iRobot_Functions irf = new iRobot_Functions();
        irf.Wait(3000);
        irf.Send(admUsr);
        System.out.println(admUsr);
    }
}
```

Using this functions:

```
package iRobot;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class iRobot_Functions {
  Robot r;
  public void Wait(int i)
  {
      Robot r;
      try {
          r = new Robot();
          r.delay(i);
      } catch (AWTException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(iRobot_Functions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
  }
  // pressionar teclas
  public void Press(int keyCode) {
      try {
        r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(keyCode);
        r.delay(200);
        r.keyRelease(keyCode);
        r.delay(200);
      } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(iRobot_Functions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
  }
    public void Send(String s) {
        if (null == s) return;
        Robot r = null;
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        try {
            for (char c : chars) {
                int code = c;
                int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(code);
                r = new Robot();
                r.delay(40);
                r.keyPress(keyCode);
                r.keyRelease(keyCode);
            } 
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

on system.outprintln printted right
HOMP\adm03!@

But when Send printted wrong
homp\adm0312

Ignoring shifts one
homp instead of HOMP
1 instead of !
2 instead of @
https://barrabase.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/teclado-atalhos-dicas.jpg

Is anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I've edited my post with full code, how to BUMP my post?

Comment: I don't know `Robot`, and I don't know what is printing out the second string.  But I will point out that `KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar()` returns an id that identifies the *key* on the keyboard, not the character being typed. Thus it does not indicate whether the shift or control keys are being pressed.  It appears that your second string is just the first string without the shift key.

Comment: Soluction for who have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101625/how-do-you-determine-if-a-character-requires-the-shift-key-to-be-down-to-be-type